# invalid input syntax for type numeric: "CE_GFS"

Tags: postgresql

I want to print column value of my table in a postgresql function.
I have created a function as below:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_col() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    row TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN
        SELECT col1  FROM TABLE
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '%', row.col1;
        END LOOP;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

While executing the query I am getting as error as
'invalid input syntax for type numeric: "CE_GFS"'

I am unable to find what could be the issue

Comment: `TABLE%ROWTYPE` is the type of a whole row of `TABLE`. Can `col1` of `TABLE` be assigned to that?

Comment: Yes. col1 of TABLE can be assigned.

Comment: Is it possible that it _can't_, and that's the reason for the error? If you use `TABLE.col1%TYPE`, for the declaration, and treat your `row` directly as a variable rather than using `row.col1`, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable of type `TABLE%ROWTYPE`, it's a [row type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES) that can hold a complete row of `TABLE`. When you later try to assign specific columns of that same table into the variable (`SELECT col1  FROM TABLE`), it attempts to assign them in order.

So, that `FOR row` effectively means you're attempting to assign a single value with type type of `col1` to a variable with the same type as `TABLE`'s *first* column.

In this case the error message:

> invalid input syntax for type numeric: "CE_GFS"

indicates that `col1` holds a string, but that the first column of `TABLE` is numeric.

If you really intend to iterate over single values, replace `row TABLE%ROWTYPE;` with:

```
row TABLE.col1%TYPE;
```

and replace your use of it with:

```
RAISE NOTICE '%', row;
```

You may also want to give `row` a different name, to make clear that it's just holding a single string.